# Combing two Python Codes together in a custom print

Tags: python

I've been working on a small weather station for APRS using Direwolf and some python scripts on my RPi 3.

My dilemma seems simple, but I'm lacking in python knowledge.

I have my main code for my BMP180 sensor that outputs data in a specific format for the temp and pressure. However, I added a humidity sensor but I've been unable to combine the code to get the outputted format that I need.

Here's my main code with the code at the bottom that I need added in to get the desired output (also shown at the bottom for the print job)
i.e.

> @050501z000/000g000t042r000p000P000h42b9999 RPI

Where

> h42=h+humidity percentage.

```
#Main BMP180 code

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
import smbus
import time
import sys
from ctypes import c_short

DEVICE = 0x77 # Default device I2C address


bus = smbus.SMBus(1) # Rev 2 Pi uses 1 

def convertToString(data):
  # Simple function to convert binary data into
  # a string
  return str((data[1] + (256 * data[0])) / 1.2)

def getShort(data, index):
  # return two bytes from data as a signed 16-bit value
  return c_short((data[index] << 8) + data[index + 1]).value

def getUshort(data, index):
  # return two bytes from data as an unsigned 16-bit value
  return (data[index] << 8) + data[index + 1]

def readBmp180Id(addr=DEVICE):
  # Chip ID Register Address
  REG_ID     = 0xD0
  (chip_id, chip_version) = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addr, REG_ID, 2)
  return (chip_id, chip_version)

def readBmp180(addr=DEVICE):
  # Register Addresses
  REG_CALIB  = 0xAA
  REG_MEAS   = 0xF4
  REG_MSB    = 0xF6
  REG_LSB    = 0xF7
  # Control Register Address
  CRV_TEMP   = 0x2E
  CRV_PRES   = 0x34 
  # Oversample setting
  OVERSAMPLE = 3    # 0 - 3

  # Read calibration data
  # Read calibration data from EEPROM
  cal = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addr, REG_CALIB, 22)

  # Convert byte data to word values
  AC1 = getShort(cal, 0)
  AC2 = getShort(cal, 2)
  AC3 = getShort(cal, 4)
  AC4 = getUshort(cal, 6)
  AC5 = getUshort(cal, 8)
  AC6 = getUshort(cal, 10)
  B1  = getShort(cal, 12)
  B2  = getShort(cal, 14)
  MB  = getShort(cal, 16)
  MC  = getShort(cal, 18)
  MD  = getShort(cal, 20)

  # Read temperature
  bus.write_byte_data(addr, REG_MEAS, CRV_TEMP)
  time.sleep(0.005)
  (msb, lsb) = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addr, REG_MSB, 2)
  UT = (msb << 8) + lsb

  # Read pressure
  bus.write_byte_data(addr, REG_MEAS, CRV_PRES + (OVERSAMPLE << 6))
  time.sleep(0.04)
  (msb, lsb, xsb) = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addr, REG_MSB, 3)
  UP = ((msb << 16) + (lsb << 8) + xsb) >> (8 - OVERSAMPLE)

  # Refine temperature
  X1 = ((UT - AC6) * AC5) >> 15
  X2 = (MC << 11) / (X1 + MD)
  B5 = X1 + X2
  temperature = (B5 + 8) >> 4

  # Refine pressure
  B6  = B5 - 4000
  B62 = B6 * B6 >> 12
  X1  = (B2 * B62) >> 11
  X2  = AC2 * B6 >> 11
  X3  = X1 + X2
  B3  = (((AC1 * 4 + X3) << OVERSAMPLE) + 2) >> 2

  X1 = AC3 * B6 >> 13
  X2 = (B1 * B62) >> 16
  X3 = ((X1 + X2) + 2) >> 2
  B4 = (AC4 * (X3 + 32768)) >> 15
  B7 = (UP - B3) * (50000 >> OVERSAMPLE)

  P = (B7 * 2) / B4

  X1 = (P >> 8) * (P >> 8)
  X1 = (X1 * 3038) >> 16
  X2 = (-7357 * P) >> 16
  pressure = P + ((X1 + X2 + 3791) >> 4)

  return (temperature/10.0 * 9/5 +32,pressure/10)

def main():

  (chip_id, chip_version) = readBmp180Id()
#  print "Chip ID     :", chip_id
 # print "Version     :", chip_version


  (temperature,pressure)=readBmp180()
  print time.strftime("@%d%H%Mz")+('000g000t0{0:0.0f}r000p000P000h00b{1:0.0f} RPI'.format(temperature, pressure))



if __name__=="__main__":
   main()


#Code that needs to be added

import Adafruit_DHT
humidity = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.AM2302, 17)

if humidity <= 99:
   print('{0:0.0f}'.format(humidity))
else:
   print('00')

#Desired output of print
#print time.strftime("@%d%H%Mz")+('000g000t0{0:0.0f}r000p000P000h00b{1:0.0f} RPI'.format(temperature, pressure))
#Where h00 = h(humidity output of the sensor)
```

Comment: what is a problem ? what did you try ?

Comment: I tried adding the codes in identical to how it's shown at the bottom. With different arrangements. The best I could get was the humidity sensor data appeared on the line before the one it needs to be in. And I'm unsure how to properly import and code it together.

Comment: why don't you put this in `main()` and use one `print` in `main()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Put `import` at the beginning of script and rest in `main()`

You can use `{:02.0f}` to get always two digits - ie. `h09`

```
import Adafruit_DHT

def main():

  chip_id, chip_version = readBmp180Id()

  temperature, pressure = readBmp180()

  humidity = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.AM2302, 17)

  if humidity > 99:
     huminidy = 0

  print time.strftime("@%d%H%Mz") + '000g000t0{:0.0f}r000p000P000h{:02.0f}b{:0.0f} RPI'.format(temperature, huminidy, pressure)


if __name__=="__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: Works perfectly aside from one thing. The > 99 needs to return a double 00 instead of a single 0. Thanks a million though. Somehow my mind couldn't sort it out tonight.

Comment: Here's another slight issue I'm unable to resolve yet. On some occasions humidity returns a wild number of 3300%, I need to make an if > 100 to basically recheck the humidity until correct. And another, if = 100 to replace with 00.